# Using List in C# Interface, How to return and set the List Value

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to practice OOP. I have a class called Cinema and interface called location. Location Interface has List type and when I am trying to add the location name, It is giving error. Any direction or suggestion will be great -

The error is: "The name 'cinema_location' does not exist in the current context."

```
namespace MOSS.Interfaces
{
    interface loc
    {
        List<string> location { get; set;}
    }
}


namespace MOSS
{
    class Cinema : Interfaces.loc
    {

        List<string> cinema_location = new List<string>();

        cinema_location.Add("location1");
        cinema_location.Add("location2");
        public List<string> location
        {
            get
            {
            return cinema_location;
            }

            set
            {
                cinema_location = value;
            }
        }

        public void DisplayCinema()
        {
            string loc;
            string Session;
            for(int i = 0; i < cinema_location.Count; i++)
            {
                loc = cinema_location[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Cinema Location: {0}", loc);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the  error?

Comment: Your method calls aren't within a method. `cinema_location.Add("location1");` can't just be in the body of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your c `cinema_location.Add(...)`s have to be inside a method (you cannot execute code directly in class scope).

It seems like you want these names added at object creation, right? In that case you need a constructor and add thr method calls there:

```
class Cinema
{
    List<string> cinema_locations = new List<string>();
    public Cinema()
    {
         cinema_locations.Add("location1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I put it in a new method called addLocation instead of constructor and also define that method in the loc interface as well.Is that will be a good way to structure this!!!!

Comment: of course you could implement a `addLocation` method. either you force it in the interface directly or you give the 'user' of the interface the choice of how to fill the list.

Answer (score 2):

A code like this one

```
cinema_location.Add("location1");
cinema_location.Add("location2");
```

can't be put wherever you like. In particular, it has to be put in a **method**, could be a class constructor.

Try

```
public class Cinema
{
  List<string> cinema_location = new List<string>();

  public Cinema()
  {
     cinema_location.Add("location1");
     cinema_location.Add("location2");
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a **constructor** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors):

```
Public Cinema()
{
    cinema_location.Add("location1");
    cinema_location.Add("location2");
}
```

Comment: actually it is called a constructor